# How can I do a query using Django?

Tags: sql, django, django-models

Hello I am looking for the equivalent of  SQL queries using Django for instance :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CONDITION

SELECT COLUMN_1 FROM TABLE WHERE CONDITION

UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN_1 = 'values' WHERE condition
```

I saw different things on the internet so I would like to be sure that is why I ask your help.

Thank you !

Comment: What did you see on the internet? Didn't it work?

Comment: Check [django docs on queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/). They have details on how to use conditions, query only 1 column and update values.

Comment: Sorry but actually I don't understand the difference between `filter()` and `get()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899919/django-queryset-and-filter-vs-get/42900163

Comment: Thank you I understoof but I don't find how can I do to select just one column ? like Select column_1 from ...

Comment: Use [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

Comment: @Gasanov: please do *not* use `value_list(..)` only in very rare cases, one should select only one column. You should see a table as a collection of model entities, not that much as "records". It also removes the behavior you defined on the models. Only in some cases, like some advanced `GROUP BY`s, this is a good idea.

Comment: @BruceCollins: it is usually better not to think in terms of SQL and then revert these to Django ORM calls. You should think the other way around: how can I retrieve entity objects, and filter/update/... these properly. To some extent, you can see SQL as an "implementation detail" of the ORM.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah, pretty much better to just get model instances and loop over specific field.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter querys in django like this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(description='Hello Wolrd!')
```

This returns QuerySet with all MyModel that the description equals Hello Wolrd!

Exemple of return:

```
<QuerySet [<MyModel: MyModel object (1)>,<MyModel: MyModel object (2)>,...]>
```

You can see that the return is Queryset with objects MyModel

If you want only some fields you can try it:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(description='Hello Wolrd!').values('name','id')
```

This returns only name and id.

Exemple of returns:

```
<QuerySet [{'name': 'Joao', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'Lucas', 'id': 2}, ...]>
```

This returns is like dict

If you can update value from model you need like this:

For one model:

```
m = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
m.name = 'OlokoMeu'
m.save()
```

or

With filter objects

```
MyModel.objects.filter(description='Hello World!').update(name='Lorem')
```

for more informations :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update