# How to filter the objects related to foreign key model in django Views.py

Tags: python, django

I have models.py as like this:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    sub = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    sub = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=800, unique=True)
```

urls.py

```
 path('view/<subj>/', views.PostDetail, name='post_detail'),
```

views.py

```
def PostDetail(request, subj):
    content = Post.objects.get(sub=subj)
```

But I'm getting this error when i pass subj as sig from url,

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sig'
```

How to get all the objects related to the query subj i.e "sub" in Post model?

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting more than one object (queryset) then, use [`filter()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42900163/10860596):

```
def PostDetail(request, subj):
    content = Post.objects.filter(sub__sub=subj)
```

*invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sig'* : Because, in your `get()` method, `sub` was expecting some kind of `id`(integer). But, you have passed `string`. So, by going to specific field inside `Subject` model and pointing to `sub` using `underscore(__)` you should get what you weere expecting.

[Lookups using underscore](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Answer (score 0):

in your `urls.py` give subj type, if subj is String add `<str:***>`:

```
path('view/<str:subj>/', views.PostDetail, name='post_detail'),
```

views.py:

```
def PostDetail(request, subj):
    content = Post.objects.filter(sub__sub=subj)
```

use filter to search Post.sub, because sub is ForeignKey, so use sub__sub.